# How to decode or unpack eval('eval(function code

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, decode, unpack

I'm trying to find a solution for decoding or unpacking `eval('eval(function code` javascript, the packed javascript code seems strange too me due to the nested eval!

I tried several online Unpacker-tools, but so far with no success. If I decode the eval code then it's not working or executing. My question is how can I decode or unpack `eval('eval(function code` in javascript?

*Here's the example on js-fiddle*: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltfz1hsy/1

Comment: Can I ask you how did you acquire this script? After brief look I think this one is specific for proper domain OR some malware JS. Where did you find this code?

Comment: I find from  a blogger template.

Comment: I don't think it's ethical to reverse engineer someone's code here, sorry